# Conway's Monster

Tags: code-golf, math, kolmogorov-complexity, integer, restricted-source

This challenge is in honor of mathematician [John Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway) who [passed away April 11, 2020 due to COVID-19](https://dailyvoice.com/new-jersey/mercer/obituaries/covid-19-kills-renowned-princeton-mathematician-game-of-life-inventor-john-conway-in-3-days/786461/). He was famous for coming up with the [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) cellular automaton and [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway#Major_areas_of_research) [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_things_named_after_John_Horton_Conway) mathematical contributions such as the [surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) and the [monster group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_group).

The advanced math of those topics is out scope for this programming challenge, though I strongly recommend people watch the various [Numberphile videos about Conway](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLt5AfwLFPxWIL8XA1npoNAHseS-j1y-7V). In [one of those videos](https://youtu.be/xOCe5HUObD4?t=453) Conway says that he'd like to know why the [monster group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_group) exists before he dies. It's unfortunately too late for that now but we can honor his memory in a very small way by exploring in code the strange number associated with the group.

## Challenge

The [monster group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_group) is the largest [sporadic simple group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sporadic_group) in the branch of [group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory) in mathematics. But the only thing to know for this challenge is that its [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)), or number of elements it contains is:

```
808017424794512875886459904961710757005754368000000000
```

Your task is to write a program that outputs this number. *However*, to keep this from being trivial, your program may not contain any digits, 0 through 9. That is, **your program may not contain any of the ten characters `0123456789`**.

Your output must be the precise digits of the number:

```
808017424794512875886459904961710757005754368000000000
```

or the digits with appropriate commas:

```
808,017,424,794,512,875,886,459,904,961,710,757,005,754,368,000,000,000
```

<sup>(Commas `,` are allowed in your code.)</sup>

Any [usual output method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods?answertab=votes#tab-top) is valid. No input should be required. **The shortest program in bytes wins.**

If it helps anyone the factorization of the number is:

```
2^46 * 3^20 * 5^9 * 7^6 * 11^2 * 13^3 * 17 * 19 * 23 * 29 * 31 * 41 * 47 * 59 * 71
```

<sup>(Factorization is not valid output.)</sup>

Comment: Are non-Ascii digits like `⁴` acceptable?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Certainly.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of the 2014 version of this challenge?  The only difference what number is being output.

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter Yeah, to an extent. This number is more complex and may have different strategies - though I understand you could say that about lots of numbers. If the community wants it closed then so be it ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I don't consider this a duplicate at all, just another challenge in the same genre. Different target numbers are quite different--ranging from easy targets (like 2014) to theoretically difficult ones (such as incompressible numbers in the sense of Chaitin). Interesting ones would usually be between these two extremes, like this monster challenge. They're like any code-golf puzzle--you need to find hidden patterns in the target that you can exploit. But different numbers have different patterns! (That this challenge can be interesting is borne out by the variety of solutions already posted.)

Comment: I'm disappointed there aren't any solutions that actually use the group theory aspect of this number (no clue how to in R which is the only language I'm any good at, but maybe in something like mathematica?)

Comment: I feel obligated to link to the real codegolf monster related to John Conway: tetris made in Game of life: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11880

Comment: For anyone interested, [here](https://pastebin.com/FpsbAhi3) are all the divisors of Conway's monster whose hexadecimal representation consists of letters exclusively. (Which is what [the 2nd version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203528/58563) in my answer is based upon.)

Comment: Because code golf doesn’t favour unreadable languages enough ;)

Comment: It's a pity that an homage to John Conway excludes [FRACTRAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FRACTRAN), which doesn't have a clearly-defined source encoding but is fundamentally made of integer literals.

Answer (score 22):

## [Sledgehammer](https://github.com/tkwa/Sledgehammer), 4 bytes

<sup>31 bits, to be overly specific</sup> 
<sup>please upvote the author of this awesome language instead of me</sup>

```
⣶⣖⡥⣕
```

(this is a very awesome Mathematica compressor, and it ***really*** excels at compressing code with only a few powerful built-ins)

In this case, the built-ins are `GroupOrder` and `MonsterGroupM`, because of course they exist.

In case this somehow helps, the exact bits contained in the code are `01110111 01110101 10110010 1011010`, the corresponding Mathematica code is `GroupOrder@MonsterGroupM[]`, and the internal suffix code is `call["MonsterGroupM", 0], call["GroupOrder", 1]`, where 0 and 1 are the argument counts.

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 61 bytes

Port of [Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203529/88546).

*-5 bytes thanks to @Surclose Sputum!*

```python
for i in"  @@G^dddrstuuuvwxxy{|~~~~~":True*=ord(i)
print True
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPSUHBwcE9LiUlpai4pLS0tKy8oqKyuqYOBJSsQopKU7Vs84tSNDI1uQqKMvNKFEBC//8DAA)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>60</s> 58 bytes

*Thanks to @Surculose Sputum for saving 2 more bytes!*

```python
k=True
for i in b"?G^dddrstuuuvwxxy{|~~~~":k*=i+i
print(k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9s2pKg0lSstv0ghUyEzTyFJyd49LiUlpai4pLS0tKy8oqKyuqYOCJSssrVsM7UzuQqKMvNKNLI1//8HAA)

Comment: [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPSUHBwcE9LiUlpai4pLS0tKy8oqKyuqYOBJSsQopKU7Vs84tSNDI1uQqKMvNKFEBC//8DAA)

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9s2pKg0lSstv0ghUyEzTyFJSUHBwcE9LiUlpai4pLS0tKy8oqKyuqYOBJSssrVsM7kKijLzSjSyNf//BwA) with a bytestring in Python 3.

Comment: @ovs Thanks, funnily enough I tried to use a b-string in Python 2. I guess I forgot that it only works in Python 3.

Comment: What is this `True*=ord(i)`? How does that work?

Comment: Somehow in Python2, `True` and `False` are modifiable variables. @justhalf

Comment: Another [61 byter](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9hWycGhtLauTokrLb9IIVMhM09JTVPfytrO1T2tUkm7GAStQopKU7Vs84tSNDI1uQqKMvNKFEBC//8DAA) in Python 2. I tried to gather all cubes into a common string, but couldn't save enough characters. :(

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9s2pKg0lSstv0ghUyEzTyFJyd49LiUlpai4pLS0tKy8oqKyuqYOCJSssrVsM7UzuQqKMvNKNLI1//8HAA) in Python 3 by doubling each character before multiplying together.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum thanks! Clever improvement

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Indeed, it saves me 3 bytes in my answer too!

Comment: Bit of a late reply, but for Python 3 you can sub "True" with just 1 because you dont need a modifiable variable that is also a built in any more.

Comment: @Underslash Well, the source code cannot contain numbers...

Comment: @dingledooper You know, that would make sense :)

Answer (score 15):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁴Ḥ®x“ÆÑ¥©µ"µ£€× œ‘;Æ¡
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9qZWxsef//4oG04bikwq544oCcw4bDkcKlwqnCtSLCtcKj4oKsw5cgxZPigJg7w4bCof//)**

#### How?

$$|M|=13\times 43!+16\times 42!+4\times 41!+6\times 40!+9\times 39!+34\times 38!+9\times 37!+2\times 36!+12\times 35!+17\times 34!+32\times 33!+30\times 32!$$

So...

```
⁴Ḥ®x“ÆÑ¥©µ"µ£€× œ‘;Æ¡ - Main Link: no arguments
⁴                     - literal 16
 Ḥ                    - double = 32
  ®                   - recall from register = 0
   x                  - times = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    “ÆÑ¥©µ"µ£€× œ‘    - list of code-page indices = [13,16,4,6,9,34,9,2,12,17,32,30]
                  ;   - concatenate = [13,16,4,6,9,34,9,2,12,17,32,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
                   Æ¡ - convert from factorial base to integer
```

---

For what it's worth a naive base-250 compression is 25 bytes AND contains digits: `“Æ4Ḍ⁹|oGO⁷pNJ6þḤ)Ė⁽u2ẏẏż’`

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that factorial representation of the number

Comment: Neither did I, but I don't think it's all that unexpected for it to have a fairly nice representation in the factorial number system.

Comment: Darn, this was the method I was going to use - iterated and descending factorials. Absolutely well done, mate. Very crisp solution!

Comment: @Mathgeek go for it - unless your solution was also going to be in Jelly and would be longer I see no reason not to use the same idea!

Answer (score 12):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>32</s> 29 bytes

```
ＩΠＥ/Gdddrstuuuvwxxy{|~~~~~⊗℅ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npXnFrzfs1TfPSUlpai4pLS0tKy8oqKyuqYOBB51TX/U0npu5///AA) Explanation: Converts the characters to their ASCII character codes, doubles them, then takes the product. Edit: Saved 3 bytes by porting @SurculoseSputum's golf of @dingledooper's Python 3 answer.

However, Charcoal can just compress the output text... except that compression of the whole text includes an `8`, so you have to print it in two parts:

```
”)¶″³L⬤j$a◧EτB⊟[βω⁵↓≧Ｏ””|～ⅉE
```

(Compressing the string in the first program doesn't help as the resulting string contains a digit.)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJwsDCwNDcxMjE3NLE1NDIwtzUwsLMxNTS0sDE0szQ3NDA3NTcwMDU3NTE2ExJ05oLrg0GgIL////XLcsBAA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Comment: I still see a "6" there.

Comment: @Almo Thanks; I discovered that I'd also pasted the wrong link anyway. The new one is a byte longer sadly.

Answer (score 8):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>34</s> 32 bytes

*Thanks @my pronoun is monicareinstate for shaving 2 bytes!*

Someone has to do this...

```
Print@GroupOrder@MonsterGroupM[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxMG9KL@0wL8oJbXIwTc/r7gktQgs4hsd@/8/AA)

Comment: 32 bytes by `@` instead of `//` and `[]`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@gKDOvxMG9KL@0wL8oJbXIwTc/r7gktQgs4hsd@/8/AA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: Alright, thanks! @mypronounismonicareinstate

Comment: You can save a few bytes by writing `GroupOrder@MonsterGroupM[]&`. This is a function (which on here is equivalent to a program by default) that outputs the correct number regardless of the input.

Comment: Even shorter would be `GroupOrder@*MonsterGroupM`, which is the same as Greg Martin's function when called with no arguments

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 67 bytes

```ruby
"nn/HM|Q:iv^YxO[e}%W}}WTBn}}}}}}}}".bytes{|i|$><<(i+?A.ord)%?_.ord}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/XykvT9/DtybQKrMsLrLCPzq1VjW8tjY8xCmvFgqU9JIqS1KLq2sya1TsbGw0MrXtHfXyi1I0Ve3jQXTt//8A)

By coincidence, the range of digit pairs is 0 to 94, which only just fits in the ASCII range.

`(i+?A.ord)%?_.ord` = `(i+65)%95`. The 65 offset ensures no digit characters in the magic string.

By default numbers are printed without leading zeros, so digit pairs in the range `00..09` require two characters in the magic string. The other digit pairs require one character.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 35 bytes

```
'nTIFBCAAAAA@A@A@A@@A'tfYqwIEW-^X$p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Xz0vxNPNydkRBBwg0MFRvSQtsrDc0zVcNy5CpeD/fwA)

#### Explanation

This uses the prime factorization of the number:

\$ 808017424794512875886459904961710757005754368000000000 \\ = 2^{46} · 3^{20} · 5^9 · 7^6 · 11^2 · 13^3 · 17 · 19 · 23 · 29 · 31 · 41 · 47 · 59 · 71. \$

```
'nTIFBCAAAAA@A@A@A@@A' % Push this string
t                      % Duplicate
f                      % Indices of nonzero chars: gives [1 2 3 ... 19 20]
Yq                     % n-th prime, element-wise: gives [2 3 5 ... 67 71]
w                      % Swap
IEW                    % Push 3, multiply by 2, exponential with base 2: gives 64
-                      % Subtract, element-wise: subtracts 64 from the code point
                       % of each character of the string. Gives [46 20 9 ... 0 1]
^                      % Element-wise power. Gives [2^46 3^20 5^9 ... 1 71]
X$                     % Convert to symbolic (to achieve arbitrary precision)
p                      % Product. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, 86 bytes

```java
v->"ᾑ䐑Ἂ㉌⊡▒д᭞ᵸ᪑".chars().forEach(c->System.out.print(~-c))
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@n5yTWFys4JuYmVfNpaCQmVeSWpSWmJyq4AfiKiiU5WemKCRrhIGoMk1roFgtF5AoLkksyUxW8FPIU7D9X6Zrp/Rw38QnEyY@3NP1uLPnUdfCdysaH02bdGHLw7XzHm7d8XDVREYIUNJLzkgsKtbQ1EvLL3JNTM7QSNa1C64sLknN1csvLdErKAK6QKNON1lT8781yKKC0qQcoEVQ@8CuyQW6VSO4BKgyPTpWIVET4tA8vWSNvNKcHKgba/8DAA)

**Explanation:**

```java
v->  // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  "ᾑ䐑Ἂ㉌⊡▒д᭞ᵸ᪑".chars().forEach(c->
     //  Loop over the characters of this string as integer codepoints:
    System.out.print(~-c))
     //   Print this integer - 1 to STDOUT
```

The string contains the characters with the codepoints:

```java
8081,17425,7946,12876,8865,59905,9618,1076,7006,7544,6801,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: [Outgolfed!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203553/16236) It's a different output and algorithm so I'm writing my own answer instead of simply golfing yours ;)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah, didn't realize that was shorter, haha. [The first version of the C answer used a similar approach.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/203543/1)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>37</s> 30 bytes

```
ØẠiⱮ“tTIFBC”;⁽<(B¤
³ÆRṁ¢ż¢*/€P
```

Encodes the number as a list of exponents to primes, probably could be optimized with cleverer builtins

```
ØẠiⱮ“tTIFBC”;⁽<(B¤
    “tTIFBC”       the string "tTIFBC"
  iⱮ               find indices of each character in
ØẠ                 the alphabet in both cases "A..Za..z"
             ⁽<( ¤ the number 16041
                B¤ converted to binary
            ;      append
```

```
³ÆRṁ¢ż¢*/€P
 ÆR         all primes below
³           100
   ṁ        shaped like
    ¢       the above line
     ż      zipped with
      ¢     the above line
       */€  exponent for each pair
          P product
```

-7 bytes by encoding the final 0/1 sequence as binary

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9qZWxsef//w5jhuqBp4rGu4oCcdFRJRkJD4oCdO@KBvTwoQsKkCsKzw4ZS4bmBwqLFvMKiKi/igqxQ//8)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>29</s> <s>28</s> 27 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @KevinCruijssen

```
•∍ýö/V$Éb´‰ŒrƶÜλFÄôS•¦¾T<×«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9vc2FiaWX//@KAouKIjcO9w7YvViTDiWLCtOKAsMWScsa2w5zOu0bDhMO0U@KAosKmwr5UPMOXwqv//w)

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 21 bytes

Answer suggested by @KevinCruijssen as a port of the Jelly answer by @JonathanAllen

```
₆ÍRžwŸ!•Pǝ½ζÄž,Ā•₆в*O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVPb4d6go/vKj@5QfNSwKOD43EN7z2073HJ0n86RBqAAUP7CJi3///8B)

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##ATsAxP9vc2FiaWX//@KAouKIjcO9w7YvViTDiWLCtOKAsMWScsa2w5zOu0bDhMO0U@KAosKmwr5UPMOXwqv//w)

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVPb4d6go/vKj@5QfNSwKOD43EN7z2073HJ0n86RBqAAUP7CJi3///8B) by porting the approach used in [_JonathanAllan_'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203532/52210).

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f2EgxRPFRw6LDnZGH1h1ac3gmkB3w/z8A) by porting the approach used in [_Bubbler_'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251331/52210)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 91 bytes

```hs
import Data.Numbers.Primes
product[p^length[';'..c]|(c,p)<-zip"hNC@<=;;;;;:;:;:;::;"primes]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5Bi8IwGETv/oqPIqioJXWTJrUGBb0IiwgeRaHGYIttEpIUy7L/vVbFN6d5h2HyzN1lWbZtURltPWwyn4W7urpI68K9LSrpeg03Vl9r4Y/mXEp18/lxkA7CUJz@h2JiRovpX2GCfLdeLXj6Yv7JPA3Me@HUVlmh@FX3oKNzykMfmk@r/cHbX9WJYOtAaGul8KDeF5YQwHgMLtcPGDbAOTDEUETxDNMEk2jGKGEsxiRJEE7iiEaIEooQoQT/xAx9GbVP) (has an extra 2 bytes for `x=`)

Probably suboptimal but I had a lot of fun writing it. I encode the prime exponents (including zeroes for the primes it doesn't have prior to 71) as a string using the character's relative distance from `:`. the rest is a simple matter of zipping the exponents against an infinite list of all primes, raising those primes to that power, and taking the product.

Edit: forgot to take the `x=` out of the source code on here.

Comment: [almost](https://tio.run/##NchNC4IwHIDxe5/ijwQWksza3IQkbxF069gL2CYp6ZS55aLoq68i@t2ep8z7a1HXztm0U60wXO/rQl50ufcPyA9Dfnzy5cwDyLL1SQihem2MuQ3W3h/P15d3dE1eyVS0I/joVCU1jMH@yuidVlv5Gd6mB94qVXAN0jTnQq3AgyCAvmwHmFhIU2CIoYjiOaYJJtGcUcJYjEmSIJzEEY0QJRQhQglexAz9Td0b)... idk why product is returning a negative number tbh

Comment: @ASCII-only it's because `length` always returns an `Int` and this number is too big to be stored as an `Int` so it overflowed into the negatives. In my code I made sure the type of `x` was ambiguous so that GHC would default it to `Integer` which is arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>84</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>81</s></sup> 83 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!
Added 2 bytes to fix a bug kindly pointed out by [gastropner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75886/gastropner).

```c
*s;f(){for(s=L"nn/HM|Q:iv^YxO[e}%W}}WTBn}}}}}}}}";*s;)printf("%d",(*s+++'A')%'_');}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/1@r2DpNQ7M6Lb9Io9jWRykvT9/DtybQKrMsLrLCPzq1VjW8tjY8xCmvFgqUrIE6NAuKMvNK0jSUVFOUdDS0irW1tdUd1TVV1ePVNa1r/wPlFHITM/M0NBWquRSAAGiDNVftfwA)

Port of [Level River St](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15599/level-river-st)'s [Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203533/9481).

Comment: Oh wait... We got a problem here. `02` :(

Comment: @newbie Yikes! Just saw that too! T_T

Comment: Sorry, [the direct approach is smaller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/203524/conways-monster/207869#207869). That `%'_'` doesn't actually save anything.

Comment: Think you need to sacrifice two bytes to change those numbers into chars to avoid digits.

Comment: @gastropner Oops, miss that.  Now fixed.  Well spotted - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s><sup>27</sup></s> 25 bytes

*Thanks to Underslash for -2 bytes because numbers.*

```
»$⇩∪£¼ɾǏ℅yṙ`₆gǏ¦¨λ»kεk×**
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%BB%24%E2%87%A9%E2%88%AA%C2%A3%C2%BC%C9%BE%C7%8F%E2%84%85y%E1%B9%99%60%E2%82%86g%C7%8F%C2%A6%C2%A8%CE%BB%C2%BBk%CE%B5k%C3%97**&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Unfortunately, the compressed form of the number contains a `2` and a `0`. This is a different number, multiplied by another number multiplied by another number, to get the target number.

```
»$⇩∪£¼ɾǏ℅yṙ`₆gǏ¦¨λ»        # Push 11482618231106483731969943632999939453125
                   kε      # Push 32768
                     k×    # 2147483648
                       **  # Multiply all the numbers
                           # Implicit output
```

Comment: [25 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%BB%24%E2%87%A9%E2%88%AA%C2%A3%C2%BC%C9%BE%C7%8F%E2%84%85y%E1%B9%99%60%E2%82%86g%C7%8F%C2%A6%C2%A8%CE%BB%C2%BBk%CE%B5k%C3%97**&inputs=&header=&footer=) by dividing the number by 2^31 and 2^15, compressing that, and then multiplying to get the correct output.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 93 bytes

```
FromDigits[LetterNumber/@Characters@"h h agdbdgideabhgehhfdeii difaga geg  egedcfh         "]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcgxCkJBDAXAq4R/AU8gLChWIvZikd1kX1KsQn48f7RxylmcpovTBxeOdYn3Ojs898dVMzVun9U1Du1kHDx@sbfNyIghXeCi3A1qNkXdSXwymKAgUqiMafS3Pese/kpqqPoC)

Comment: `GroupOrder[MonsterGroupM[]]` saves 66 bytes.

Comment: @MeesdeVries of course there is a mathematica built in... it is already posted in another answer

Comment: Oops, I didn't even read all the answers before commenting. My bad. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Core utilities, 67 bytes

```bash
tr o-z /-:<<<xpxpqwtrtwytuqrxwuxxvtuyyptyvqwqpwuwppuwutsvxppppppppp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcGxEYAwDAPAVVggR89lGajokBM5slneVPxf57yrOLanvdvejt57IGDioJJuI@QRi54J5jIZ5AJczrkCv6oP)

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 50 bytes

```matlab
prod(primes('G').^sym('hNC@<=;;;;;:;:;:;::;'-':'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/oCg/RaOgKDM3tVhD3V1dUy@uuDJXQz3Dz9nBxtYaBKwg0MpaXVfdSl1T8/9/AA)

Comment: This deserves more votes! I'm impressed!

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>183</s> <s>171</s> 170 bytes

```
++++++++[>+++++++>++++++<<-]>.>.<.>.+.<-.---.>+.<.+++.++.>++.+.
----.+.<-.-.>+++.<+..--.>-.+.<+++..>-----.++++.<.---.>---.<+.>.
-.<.--.++.>..<--.++.--.-.-.+++.++.>.........
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1RCoAwDEMPNJITlF5E/FBBEMEPwfPPtKsWuj7SNFvv5bj2Zzt7b1WTF9Q0w@x0mrrRQAB0EbVUizVCRe1DETUynKmGIBym3I6YeGR0HYWScVRIEiIL/zf8qvcX)

Linebreaks added for readability so not included in the byte count.

Answer (score 3):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sub><s>82</s></sub>, 76 bytes

#### *Kudos to @ceilingcat for -6 bytes*

```cpp
void f(){for(auto s:L"ƴ")printf("%i",s);printf("%i%i%i",!f,!f,!f);};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv6vnJmXnFOakmqTXFySkplv978sPzNFIU1Dszotv0gjsbQkX6HYykfpc@vEiR@Xr531cW/v6s8zZu3@PGdP44eJ0xZ/Wt00/9iWz81TGpQ0C4oy80rSNJRUM5V0ijWtEVwQVNJRTIMgTeta6/9AKYXcxMw8kD0aQJH/AA)

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 82 bytes

```cpp
void f(){for(auto s:L"ƴ")printf("%i",s);printf("%i%i%i",NULL,NULL,NULL);};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv6vnJmXnFOakmqTXFySkplv978sPzNFIU1Dszotv0gjsbQkX6HYykfpc@vEiR@Xr531cW/v6s8zZu3@PGdP44eJ0xZ/Wt00/9iWz81TGpQ0C4oy80rSNJRUM5V0ijWtEVwQVNLxC/XxQRCa1rXW/4EKFHITM/NAtmkARf4DAA)

My first ever Code Golf submission! :)

Explanation: The loop part of the function prints a decimal representation for each Unicode character in the string. I was really stumped as to how to print zeros without being allowed to have `0` in the code. I just added `NULL` characters cast to `int`.

Comment: Also, welcome to CGCC!

Comment: @ceilingcat - Thanks for the welcome and the tips. Of course! A boolean of a function name always exists. That's clever.

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv6vnJmXnFOakmqTXFySkplv9z8zr0QhTUOzOi2/SAPELrbyUfrcOnHix@VrZ33c27v684xZuz/P2dP4YeK0xZ9WN80/tuVz85QGJc2CIqDqNA0l1UwlnWJNawQXBJV0FNMgSNO6FmxFbmJmHsgWDZAAAA) by replacing `auto` and `void` with `int`, and removing the semi-colon at the end.

Comment: @StealingMana You can't keep `#include<cstdio>` out of your code as it's needed for your function to work. In other words it has to be it part of your byte count.

Comment: Suggest `int` instead of `auto`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
“ ½‘!P×“ḥɗeŀƊ’
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxyFQ3sfNcxQDDg8Hch5uGPpyempRxuOdT1qmPn/PwA)

Just saw alephalpha's answer before edit and thought "what if I port it to Jelly?" and it worked.

Uses the formula from [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60329/the-mystery-string-printer-robbers/60581#comment145791_60581):

> `31!10!27079205916672`

then I noticed that `27079205916672` is a multiple of 32, so I changed the formula to

> `32!10!846225184896`

cutting one more byte from the compressed number.

The Jelly code does "`“ ½‘` (32, 10) `!P` factorial each and product `×` times `“ḥɗeŀƊ’` 846225184896".

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>79 78</s>  58 bytes

*Saved 20 (!) bytes thanks to @tsh*

A port of [Neil's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203529/58563).

```javascript
_=>eval(Buffer("?@^ddrtuuuvwxxy{|~~~~Ȁ掀").join`n*`+'n')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1i61LDFHw6k0LS21SEPJ3iEuJaWopLS0tKy8oqKyuqYOCE40POtrUNLUy8rPzEvI00rQVs9T1/yfnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66RpqGp@R8A)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 93 bytes

```javascript
_=>eval('ZxEDCCCCBAECEBBBBn*ZxEAAFEEEFECn*ZxFFCn*ZxFDDAAEn*ZxAZZZZZZZZZZn'.replace(/Z/g,+[]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYhtCoQgFEWXkzV9rKCBlz4XYUSI84pCVCqi3ZsRzPlz7zmrPvVutiUclfM/ilMbx/ZLp7YsUxcKnugAOXYJV6QEIBFRIn9MyneEAMDngfrjsnqjYLUh1qhmLj/9kOfReLd7S7X1M5tYCjc)

The idea here was to look for factorizations of \$N\$ with factors whose hexadecimal representation only contains letters and \$0\$'s, so that we only need to replace \$0\$'s with a substitute character.

There are countless possibilities. We use this one:

```javascript
0xEDCCCCBAECEBBBB * 0xEAAFEEEFEC * 0xFFC * 0xFDDAAE * 0xA0000000000
```

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 101 bytes

```javascript
_=>eval("FxHOOFdNebfLLMHOGdFMcFGKKffKn*In**HFn<<JLn".replace(/[A-Z]/g,c=>c.charCodeAt()%(~[]+[+[]])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DczBCoMgGADgdwkGWqteoIIYWJs27xMZ7ldrQzQsYqe9euv6Hb6P2tQC8T2vuQ/a7Lben3VjNuVQQr4950TfzcsyNvS802QA0lFqLfXp1adpT3xV3ZhPimhmp8CgUrT5Q5bjGeoGCphUvBxtuyJ8Qj8hM5EJKTHGOwS/BGcKF0Zk0QF/)

The encoded expression is:

```javascript
0x2990d8ebf667291d07c0155ff5n*3n**20n<<46n
```

Comment: Maybe [`_=>eval(Buffer("  @@G^dddrstuuuvwxxy{|~~~~~").join('n*')+'n')`](https://tio.run/##FcHtCkAwFADQV5E/NuINaPnjLbBsk7Xu1b4QefXJOZpH7ha77b4GFDKpNk1tJyM3pA9KSUvyLGNsGIUQ1vkQQjzO87qf95fTRuMGM5RzVUBB04Lg0MjG4EoUoTR9)?

Comment: Use `" ^ddrtuuuvwxxy{|~~~~~Ȁ掀"` may save 1 byte

Comment: are we allowed to end the output by a "n" like this?

Comment: @Kaddath It is notation for BigInt type. If you try to convert the result to String, the `n` will disappear. For example, you may print the result to a file by `fs.writeFileSync('1.txt', f())`. And you won't get `n` in the file.

Comment: @tsh Thanks, it's a great answer of course, however, if I would be picky, the challenge being "Your output must be the precise digits of the number", the output is not exactly right and the code would be only missing `+''` at the end..

Comment: @Kaddath Maybe this should be asked in meta as I didn't find a relevant enough post in there (but I didn't spend much time on it).

Comment: @Arnauld I was just curious, you are far more experienced in golf rules than me ^^ I particularly follow your answers because I code in JS for work, but it seems impossible to outgolf you so I usually choose PHP for my answers :D

Comment: [54](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1s6pNC0ttUhDPSBAUEs/jpUn3CpMN5mBJUEwm9WNgdVb24UBBtQ19bLyM/MSEv4n5@cV5@ek6uXkp2ukaWhq/gcA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 81 bytes

```java
v->"XPXPQWTRTWYTUQRXWUXXVTUYYPTYVQWQPWUWPPUWUTSVXPPPPPPPPP".chars().map(n->n-' ')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9PT4QwEMXvfIrJXrYYaLyvS@LFxINJWf4UYjxUFthiKaQdMMTsZ8fK6sm5TCbvN/PedGIWYXf@WGU/DgahczOdUCraTLpCOWh6d/D@iRZNLfofqVLCWngRUsOXBzBO70pWYFGga/Mgz9A7jSRopG5f30CY1vobCvD0a/GQOy541phsZyNo4LjOYbQrWMFinp5SXqZZfCp4VhR5mpUlS8s85jHjGWcs41ma5AX7qx2tLsJY4tNejESHkQ73sPfXw2YqNboY9thQMY5qIXpSyqc4PBojFuLfoGSxWPd0mJCOLjgqTXT9CbcviA3uA0tVrVu8@NvG1buu3w)

If Java's `int` allowed for (much) more than 32 bits, the following (65 bytes) would have worked:

```java
v->",--------<?DGLRT\\^hhhpppptv|".chars().reduce(',',(a,b)->a*b)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>50</s> 47 bytes

```ruby
p eval (%w(Gv/ R>t. &DhP)*" @QQH}bMA").bytes*?*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhtSwxR0FDtVzDvUxfIciuRE9BzSUjQFNLScEhMNCjNsnXUUlTL6myJLVYy17r/38A)

Thanks histocrat for -1 byte, ad Jo King for pointing out some silliness in the original answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [K4](https://kx.com/download/), 64 bytes,

**Solution:**

```
,/$.Q.a?"iaiabhecehjefbcihfiigefjjaejgbhbahfhaafhfedgiaaaaaaaaa"
```

**Explanation:**

Really boring, lookup each letter in the alphabet (e.g. "b" => 1), convert to string and flatten

```
    ,/$.Q.a?"iaiabhecehjefbcihfiigefjjaejgbhbahfhaafhfedgiaaaaaaaaa" / solution
            "iaiabhecehjefbcihfiigefjjaejgbhbahfhaafhfedgiaaaaaaaaa" / a -> 0, b -> 1 etc
       .Q.a?                                                         / lookup in built-in alphabet a-z
      $                                                              / convert to string
    ,/                                                               / flatten
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 42 bytes

```perl6
say [*] ²X*'``}}}~~~~~yuuuwr\t|{^;G'.ords
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVIhWitW4dCmCC31hITa2to6EKgsLS0tL4opqamOs3ZX18svSin@r5xQzWUUZ2SsoAWkTLWQaAUuUy0gBAqg0@ZaxkBoRALL0FDL0BBEgwSMsTPMtcyBdhoBuYaWINuNgFpBmkFiQGgJYxkbgljGWiaGEBETc7BbwfLmhly1/wE)

Uses the same strategy of reducing the ordinal values of a string by multiplication as other answers, but also multiplies each element by 2 beforehand to save a byte on representing all those powers of two.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>88</s> 78 bytes

```
foreach c"XPXPQWTRTWYTUQRXWUXXVTUYYPTYVQWQPWUWPPUWUTSVXPPPPPPPPP"[prin c - sp]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcExDoAgDADArxB2/9JiS9sQBwMYXZTg/1Mn72Zvnnormx/P7Hs9Q40KCiiUSIwYkwqrZmIzIMsoCMICwMK0ZoVfLGNed6hhCe/Y3D8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 79 bytes

```
"ᾑ䐑Ἂ㉌⊡▒д᭞ᵸ᪑"foreach(i,(-i)bitwiseComplement print)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z//1/p4b6JTyZMfLin63Fnz6Ouhe9WND6aNunClodr5z3cuuPhqomMEKCUll@UmpicoZGpo6GbqZmUWVKeWZzqnJ9bkJOam5pXolBQlJlXovn/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 41 bytes

```
*F^MC,fP_TSC\G+C\.xLG"ujgcdbbbbbabababaab
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X8stztdZJy0gPiTYOcZd2zlGr8LHXak0Kz05JQkEEiEwMen/fwA)

```
*F^MC,fP_TSC\G+C\.xLG"ujgcdbbbbbabababaab    Implicit: G=lower case alphabet

                   L "ujgcdbbbbbabababaab    For each character in the string...
                  x G                        ... find it's index in the alphabet
              +C\.                           Prepend 46 (character code of .) - these are the prime powers
           C\G                               71
          S                                  Range 1-71
      fP_T                                   Filter keep the primes in the above
     ,                                       Pair the primes with the prime powers
    C                                        Transpose
  ^M                                         Map exponent operator over each pair
*F                                           Take product of the result, implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 164 bytes

```
iiisdo{d}oiiisdo{d}oioisiiiodddoddosoiiioiiodddddoioddddoioisdododdoiiiooddoddoioddsoo{d}oiisodsodddo{d}ioisiiio{d}iodoiisiiioddoiio{d}ooiisioiioddododoiiioii{o{d}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU0xDsBACHpRH9WENnVicLzc262oTToYQRBwnbjNnyPCzBxc2PwhmicjgBy6JDZP2rtMKcsgme2V6Jw8Z2J5k36ZBfUyDewb69IlCp3KJW1HvA)

Answer (score 1):

### C (gcc), 77 bytes

```
*s;f(){for(s=L"pp!'JO~S<kx`[zQ]g kf YVDp        ";*s;)printf("%d",*s++-' ');}
```

Assumes that `wchar_t` and `int` have the same size. This way we can make the string wide and we can omit the type when declaring `s`.

A naive approach: group the digits in blocks of 1–3, each of which is an integer between 0 and 127 with no leading 0. Since character 0 can't be present in the string, characters are encoded as their value plus some constant. The constant is 32, which has the advantage of keeping all characters printable.

#### C (gcc), 78 bytes

Bonus: without relying on `wchar_t` and `int` having the same size. We save 1 byte (the `L`) by not having a wide string, but lose 1 byte because the implicit-int declaration `*s` is replaced by the explicit type name `char`.

```
f(){for(char*s="pp!'JO~S<kx`[zQ]g kf YVDp        ";*s;)printf("%d",*s++-' ');}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7M6Lb9IIzkjsUir2FapoEBR3cu/LtgmuyIhuiowNl0hO00hMsylQAEKlKy1iq01C4oy80rSNJRUU5R0tIq1tXXVFdQ1rWv/A0UVchMz80CmaoAEAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 36 bytes

`|.ab*n!?+il"ØØØØØØÕìëöøèúúæò÷õîÐÐÄp"`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v0YvMUkrT9FeOzNH6fAMJDj18JrDqw9vO7zj8IrDu4Bw2eFNh7cf3np43eEJQNhSoPT/PwA)

It's based on a hand-optimized list of partial products of the prime factors of the number, each fitting within a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt)

```
8462NG4896]y♂!♥!**
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/CxMzIz93EwtIstvLRzCbFRzOXKmpp/f8PAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
8462NG4896    # Push the integers 8,4,6,2,25,18,4,8,9,6
          ]   # Wrap the stack into a list
           y  # Join it together, and implicitly convert it to an integer: 846225184896
♂!            # Push 10!: 3628800
♥!            # Push 32!: 263130836933693530167218012160000000
**            # Multiply all three values on the stack together
              # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Javascript, 93 characters

```js
_=>'ÉÉŠ£¨×¬•ÄÑ¹´Óª¶ÀyÄ¿y~Ä¤½yyyyyyyyy'.split``.map(c=>c.charCodeAt()-'y'.charCodeAt``).join``
```

The function returns `"808017424794512875886459904961710757005754368000000000"`.

Explanation: Each character in the string is encoding two characters in the target. Because low character codes are a mess, we offset them by 121 ("y"). I also had to pad some extra 0s (y's) into the string because for instance a "y" and "yy" both convert to "0".

#### Port of Kevin Crujissen's answer (63 characters):

```js
v=>"ᾑ䐑Ἂ㉌⊡▒д᭞ᵸ᪑".split``.map(c=>~-c.charCodeAt()).join``
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 99 bytes

```
cat(match(strsplit("iaiareyhjefmihfiigefjjaejgrkhfhaafhfedgiaaaaaaaaa","")[[T]],letters)-T,sep="")
```

Fairly simple zero-based mapping from digits to letters, and using `T` as a substitute for `1`.

Answer (score 0):

## BRASCA, <s>72</s> 66 bytes

```
`B:B:;A><>AC>?;<BA?BB@>?CC:>C@;A;:A?A::?A?>=@B:::::::::`![al-mA{]x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVvrctu2Ev6vp0Ds01qqJVvOpUkUS47kpK3bJs7Y7rRnPC4DiZDFlCQYEozsSdtXT3fBiwiSEsH46pk2NgnsfnvFAlh6l2LG3UfPPP@L5XjcFyS4DNrEoWLWmPrcIcJyGEle2Yx50WOfuib8E7/Av@C/c9aIHwifTtiYTv5qNCY2DQIy8mkwofv4e69B4Gdtbe1YwIA28dm5FQjmBwSokE/Ut@jYZgEMkANNNiWGYbmWMIxmwOxpq9eQL/BnXdKQE1My6UscvBXIAX1yeqY@p/Csqz4aK48WPIY@I3MGDKhpueeEfWI@aA1/pQGZzCjIinz38ox9GGI43GRA9wdqByyD@53lMbNjucSkgqaPrSlxuTQBTAdmW1ZAhbhstnrpkAx9GGDgdCC/mIEom63TXq@zc6ZMmnKfGG1iEGDK3NBhPhWsmSOVY1TCDO0VhLZApuqbU2TZLjzN41Ats0U9j7lmk/tmMyLcaqXDGeisSnLwkoVWf6LoRLFxxoy5xAMjCGaSSyZy9qE2qurSSEYUbXQyswIyt2ybBIKDD1D4TcwYGYPB/2KCeDywhMXdnMfNZ5bNDJtzLwCin/9RKDIyQYdAh0VSHkfmvkoARxjxm6KXTiKHysotn0Pk2dYEogRsmwpTPkJwTxV3/V0YzAhMHANHwSU0aZ40Aj0YYEQDpM@0cXTGW4oWxfdZ6p@oHTLCp4uIQU4lXPB9zAN/XckE3UYOai0XZMyFgFQFnFeKZUTjqqSz3ID5otmNhlQLqIUAZ6j8l0u@AFAUHuwqs3OOBfeSxJlPNClZNcx8JkLfzXheMRLjIRlgyCaK3RyaShVwLyv8LcDsJho7hjBGQMnikWIKmDCSh7FJkj9VfMlT0oeYpGsl6YomqXKhoAhrfva4bPa4ODvjc1nsG0HsgqUBjMnuuiRSQjCSsVUud7euuEXS41a5UrqxCY9wPQ5YqcjyTd6pMnySEa2UlvQWJGUz91zMyh02epenG7savGwuWGRCM7RhwZXU5ApBcIUgNuiDNPPrRitlNQ4t24we5vkJ5nhqYYNPDKg7lJpDfQkLo80@hlwwxTpYHCTLGSQf7ji4QhUrBVx8cjUCmLVAekC6xUKiMKrTJzvKKOkjRZz95dRysuaBJYKgu52uRauuMi@eWE4@ccNEMa0i2CyDs1oMwDt8LKIkIzUzLKsmTuWcM5iUIKqekozEWXL6ahk21io1feKHrNq2ffJwNaf3tc2RHVYAoUsfJ1aTj72pgXuQ40vIWA6h/jlEgitg@@LJPROWgbCl2fIuyZTsTkHlLnXYoPh2QnYxbAaNxgmHeMLNDYT2ODxvkxDy1tTcnmCoARdqYr6Zbk@2cGhg8zkx@dwlPBReKOLhwfYkkMAs3BchT8OQEhuGQ6EuNmITRgDAEJmtV@xkMba0klz78n7UG/VeDAe7g@H@YO/F7mi4Nxq9HOzt7/cG@y9fDF/0hnvDXm9vuDfovxz1kp/3D06p3XGGn88uvsSbuijdkRHmrSiRYppzqJflnM1qSYYkbwC9HC3/jnJkBmlaEe/KFJt5k82J/qVq3dQlsqROS8ie5XNHPEbZxi31z8KDdSLX511InwO1zl2Rorol0ZfRWrYG7xbTRSEEdvTJ7WiQe6hP7qEGuUf65B5pkHusT@6xBrkn@uSeaJD7Xp/c9xrknuqTe6pB7pk@uWca5J7rk3uuQc6u4cY6YfFrDXo6nsdqxIWOcV/XCAydQDNrRIaOeV/V8GWd2JjVcBcdb/6pjr/oOMwvtQjqUPy81iPrr9jEZ1hS6BJPHmGx2NHJ2P8gmwP3Cmw2ddj4yEYud0fyDLiMD12swOXFrgSjMwi3KhZuTeSBc3PcJhRQlltoiYRWq1FcsKUA0WoPJdaM@pWCb7zfWOkY6glwad2sVYDnpZAHZBXlzObOWWsVIaWi2sSNWFEjbyhugD3c/vHMsfpS7JvoB0PTvGEHKHPZTarhpx3EdxyO8XJC3AHIjg7I7xDkm9AWlmdf3gHI73RAbkeJRbBz8B7T@mQFZZvRmwe7va2D9hupUm6GNr8DjN/oQPwTIb6@8Li7LFHfsNW1zB7IAProXwVhkTneNW5NYeMX/xoAgyZttcqS9MgScwt2wTWy0r8I@u3hybVi/ldHXd/KfPj21R3Y81sdfH8jvsOjO4D3tw48A@H9cSf4/gR8Jd53XLqJLwCnCNyTx/N8ceQ9XFkqZK8bgICGesalXEb6XMY6XIaSS3KToyeMetWgJ82onM@oBh8tedrIJz72X3Ioo3BI7gcqCfeQsBniDas85gdR@HQFh6/NPPQqIwuoX6ioF7d0usCTiztdVMl4eg0TCtI4KI3DP6nqx/iIiJSyjO7MvsoYCTZJQgPfmxRfTtHyyi4@@KzGV1fn2vi8Cv0RV7YDBeV@4fDQFbo7OHexg@u2o6kr9nDaNroeO72rsNM90sNqX7iiP@zJZBl1esU9Fd3OzsOnun6XtoU1YZ@ZP1doaQB4kK5xi@vYyqRdcpYRX9jqsPwfsgzm1JOGFnNOLMGcgHD3ysn8xjP@WEO@I2lTLpJFSsx8xm5XxsmNK2JyFZWV3ucU9HiMepxwF9dNN1UmuEtEOLh9P8EYCwSKtIn/UK0IO8@LsdwB4n4DZLOxsfWBW65k57YWiSw9@MLOh@VJb4JpDpJJJvVlrvTi2dUnenWUg@A11GHF6oCyTxAgYlmY8uPc1@yUnY8rQrXjFK10TihyLRcLoESTB33y@FncDIt/7/bJk6fL5yknjsDiVCLBC385HUBXy32QlXvRPhdpoLl5a3J3VbGff7XUALlRLfaFLH8tIOKb1SX7Sr8r0P4jS1unsNZZ1AtcQuTym9s5LiXp6pYhstcniuZ6J@mQDEydPPNbjPN8Kc5sTrmIcspFIac0qtxAbYi6bjFLzgQOtg81HI3LoxbZxoFN48Pj/YODuDmyyusWrQiFjuWl7Qg5UYqtzqWXEfgjhzQnM/UaqNWGsDb7Gxsalj5cKqpOENy9tGnw1RHaVYWOM@j9NXDWuDXEfLtczPtq3BLDLgQuied97gqf2@QHm8@rFbKLCvmVBQHU0fSmb0BQfbu0VuLaKafEdFRdt91ogLr4EcwjO99vRx2D@6uOvrzS@RiCW9@CIvr9e6uJjf9vgCZGTMwZc@/D1hL1hdXlBP93fx3oJTrQCfMdCzdmjetJivihGLuwhE5tuY4AIB@asoOY2uRD6HgViV1qHfXardRHsQWhEtEHRPQzoMBqbg6FdVCnx0Htn6nm9nPKDb9krMeuo7Lb1GB3iux@x7bXjuyZLbZrF9Ud1bwPsOhducFSdkqdnbMKCy2TKhUq22Je2UxbKu1ZTlpYkm9K1sGNiqrjSfuru3pyn@7pdQqdaNKMPvaTNBvqziX6tEVK4flMHsgE6Veu@CVl3A5VbLQv740u761fP8GvYiwBpeGUzGfMhS0@B8a@jCphgU2B7RR272ZFf3S9fiv165cUzSGylj0E8lzZEg39ZF5oworB5ToV1t/IK5TkW8/8N55aKZBdTJgnyC/scswh8WCvje@Hnsh9MlXM5vHE1/IfSNtoyJw468fcYdE3snPmCjL3uXvexpNgPgfjEODEVbhRKb32@ujo8KhHyqbn7l6jCelX4FuQrh0qDACXP4TPiBB9B3AQO2781UOj7sZhMVYJAfCxkh3GynveKxxV0v7KKqQEI4Z@OcbiZpVW7dmWEC8P0AVtWiRbSi7WZ5HcCrFri1wtbn1Rl4qJP1/@Aw)

### Explanation

```
`B:B:;A><>AC>?;<BA?BB@>?CC:>C@;A;:A?A::?A?>=@B:::::::::`            - Push the number, with the ASCII code shifted by 10
                                                        ![a  mA{]x  - Foreach in stack:
                                                           l-       -    Subtract 10 from the charcode
                                                                    - Implicitly output it
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 60 bytes

```
print(vecprod(Vec(Vecsmall("$$$G^ddhhhprstvwxxxxy{|~~~~"))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWN20KijLzSjTKUpMLivJTNMJSk0G4ODcxJ0dDSUVFxT0uJSUjI6OgqLikrLwCCCqra-qAQEkTCCBmQI2CGQkA)

Takes the product of the ASCII codes of the characters.

[Here is the Mathematica code to find the string `"$$$G^ddhhhprstvwxxxxy{|~~~~"`.](https://tio.run/##bVDfa8IwEH73rzgUfFlgSW2bFhkE3ITBxnTzLfYhq0cN2ETSOAbi395lbTcm7CAPubvvx3218nusldelatvamsajgzvIaEYZj6OY53HCoownWZbGSZ7TOE8ZZ5QnnNKEJ/EszehPzUejcq9cEwje8ICll6/KVChnEQEWpQWBEQDc6w/d6PcDykGPwKSA6bQbAiwd4lpu7CIwqTKMF3aHYrwdb7eURbM4SXmWj3tMERRXThsvls7W14hvtoXyaMLrPvCsjpu9Q7WTvdJGBRMEzp1nMsjD@qTRiydtULmVs5VTda1NJSn0t90A@90NHE6Z5mibQaKrl1PwIB@Nxwrdw@fRGjSewLVMd6p2jYdbActg27oBIYZYQlznSUiOXmAKQog/yH/3wyaBodcUl2Letl8)

Answer (score 0):

## [C#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 61 bytes

```cs
_=>"ᾐ䐐Ἁ㉋⊠░г᭝ᵷ᪐␀␀␀␀␀␀␀".Select(x=>+x+"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY@xSsRAGIRtzVP8pEo4DZszySbkkkZUBAXhCgsRWde9sJBscHfvOJED2/Oa2NgJliJYidiIz@Ar5LT2FWLkEEScbn6@Gf6hapUq2gwVFxn0z5RmRWz8ds56meeMal4K5WwxwSSnf4gdLk5jg@ZEKdiTZSZJAefGstJEcwqjkp/ALuHCUlq2qYNDIDJTdotsDgXtcaFXYHtDDAsmyXHOegssTWEASXOUpGb9Wn1UVf0yfZ/O5pe3n3cX8@urt8f64aZ@eq7vq6WFTKfPvj@1xknaGXdM025iY0QkSEhgUdqOEZRoa2Ah246N1qkyZ86@5Jq1K5gl/79CkoAZohC52Ot6OPJ8txtiPwwDz48i5EWBi12EfYyQj31vLQjRj8y2cWJMmi8)

---

Converts a series of characters to their codepoints and then converts that to a string:

```cs
ᾐ  8080
䐐  17424
Ἁ  7945
㉋  12875
⊠  8864
  59904
░  9617
г  1075
᭝  7005
ᵷ  7543
᪐  6800
␀  0
```

`␀` here is a null byte (U+0000)